# How to dynamically update CSS styled list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My application requires that users upload a set of required documents (Upload #1, Upload #2, Upload #3).  The user also has the ability to upload additional, non-required documents.

When the page is loaded for the first time, it displays the required set of documents in a list.  Each list item is initially set with `class="missing"`.  My goal is to make it so if the user uploads a a required document (one that is already on the list) it changes the list item to `class="complete"`.  However, if they upload a non-required document (one that is not on the list), it appends that document to the end of the list.

The name of the document is passed in the `category` variable from the upload form.

How would I go about this?  Is there a way to check if the item already exists in the list?

PARENT PAGE JQUERY:

```
function stopUpload(success, category){

    if (success == 1){
        $('#upload_result').html('<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span>');            
        $('#uploads ul:last').append('<li class="complete"><a href="#" target="_blank">' + category + '</a><a href="#" target="_blank" class="delete"><img src="../../media/icons/delete.png"></a><\/li>');
    }
    else {
        $('#upload_result', window.parent.document).html(
        '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span>');
    }
    $('#upload_progress').hide();
    return true;

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#imaged_documents_upload').submit( function() {

        $('#upload_progress').show();

     });

})
```

PARENT PAGE HTML:

```
<div id="uploads">
  <ul>
    <li class="missing">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Upload #1</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="delete">
            <img src="../../media/icons/delete.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="missing">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Upload #2</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="delete">
            <img src="../../media/icons/delete.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="missing">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Upload #3</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="delete">
            <img src="../../media/icons/delete.png">
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

IFRAME:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   parent.stopUpload(<?php echo $result.', \''.$category.'\''; ?> );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has everything you are after. I didn't bother trying to code in an actual file uploader, I just created three buttons to cover your three use cases.

1. User uploads required file
2. User uploads nonrequired file
3. User uploads bad file

I used the title attribute to store the name of the required file and compared this to your category variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/xg9F6/4/

```
if (success == 1) {
    //file was successfully uploaded
    $('#upload_result')
        .html('The file was uploaded successfully!')
        .removeClass()
        .addClass('success');

    var elem = $('#uploads li[title="' + category + '"]');

    //check if this was a required element
    if ($(elem).length > 0) {            
       $(elem).each( function() {
           $(this).removeClass().addClass('complete');
        });
    }
    else {
        elem = $('#uploads li:last').clone();
        $('#uploads ul').append(elem);
    }
   $(elem).append('<span>' +  category + '</span>');            
}
```

Comment: Oh, if you want to know whether file was already uploaded just place a check in the same function that adds the class `complete`. `if $(this).hasClass('complete') { ... }`